# Sharepoint 2010 web parts not displaying on one website, but are on the other

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I'm working on remolding my companies current exsisting Sharepoint site.  I installed the SP ZAP Slideshow webpart and went to the sharepoint site to insert it, and absolutely no webparts were listed.   I went into the provided Sharepoint 2010 central administration and realized that everything seems to be listed as

```
//usmvwc0wtf1srv.ww005.work.net/sitepages/
```

When the website were hosting, and it should be listing is

```
//usmvwc0wtf1srv.ww005.work.net/sites/
```

I went to the /sitepages website and all the webparts exsisted and worked, however i need to get them working on the /sites page.  Is there some way to switch it so it will not default all the webparts and content i'm uploading to the wrong page?  I feel as though the wrong default page is listed?  sorry new to all this!

Answer (score 0):

Web Parts, which you see listed and are able to insert on a page when you edit it, come from the Web Part Gallery in the site collection. They are usually installed to the gallery when you activate their site collection-scope feature. Check what features you didn't activate in the new site collection - I suspect that one of them is responsible for the installation of Web Parts you are looking for. (The scope of the feature can be site collection or site - check both.)